# Call a function and print function's name

Tags: python, function, loops, for-loop

I have a very long list of functions and I am hoping to be able to call them and have them print their name and when they are completed as show below.

```
def call(*functions):
    for f in functions:
        print(f.__name__)
        f()
        print('{} completed'.format(f.__name__))

call(lambda: (long(), lst(), of(), func(), ions()...))
```

I do not want to have to write `print(f.__name__) ... print('{} completed'.format(f.__name__))` around every function. However, in the code above it prints 'lambda' (as expected). how can I automate these function calls/print statements so it prints correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def call(*functions):
    for f in functions:
        print(f.__name__)
        f()
        print('{} completed'.format(f.__name__))

call(long, lst, of, func, ions...)
```

However, it would be more logical to use [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and simplify `call`:

```
def call(function):
    print(f.__name__)
    f()
    print('{} completed'.format(f.__name__))

map(call, (long, lst, of, func, ions...))
```

Comment: is there a way to do this where each function has different arguments? I'm playing with functools.partial, but 'functools.partial' object has no attribute `__name__`

Comment: Yes but it becomes metaprogramming using a decorator like pattern and so on.... (Sorry I'm on my phone and can't help on it more right now but ill have a look at it...)

Comment: @Apero no worries, I figured it out. Instead of `f.__name__` which creates a partial object, you need to call `f.func.__name__` which prints the function's name

Answer (score 1):

You nearly have the right idea, but you want to pass the functions *themselves* to `call` rather than a lambda.

As your code currently stands, you are only passing **one** function, the lambda, which calls the other functions between your print statements.

Change

```
call(lambda: (long(), lst(), of(), func(), ions()...))
```

to

```
call(long, lst, of, func, ions...))
```